# How to change the viewfinder (focus chart) of a NVD3 line chart programmatically?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nvd3.js

The example I'm talking about is here: http://nvd3.org/ghpages/lineWithFocus.html

What I would like to do is have preset ranges to programmatically change the visible range of the view finder. For example, I could have a buttons to only show the last 30-days of data or show ALL data. When the user clicks on either of the buttons, the viewfinder would change to reflect only data in the selected range.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to go about doing this?

Thanks,
CZ

Answer (score 4):

You can actually do this - took a little bit of digging but here's how:

```
nv.addGraph(function() {
  window.chart = nv.models.lineWithFocusChart()
  // Do whatever you need to do to set up the chart, and keep a reference to it
});

$("#preset-range").on("click", function() {
  // Get the min and max
  min = $(this).data("min")
  max = $(this).data("max")

  // Change the focus chart range programatically
  chart.brushExtent([min, max]).update()
});
```

Answer (score 1):

A suggestion for hide/unhide only, based on http://www.mkyong.com/jquery/jquery-toggle-example-to-display-and-hide-content/:

```
<button type="button" id="nv-toggle">Show View Finder</button>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#nv-toggle').click(function() {
    // make the collapse content to be shown or hide
    var toggle_switch = $(this);
    $('.nv-context').toggle(function() {
      if($(this).css('display')=='none') {
        toggle_switch.html('Show View Finder');
      } else {
        toggle_switch.html('Hide View Finder');
      }
    });
  });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit tricky finding out the solution but once you get to know it, it's pretty straight forward.

You need simply update the chart calling `d3.select('#chart svg').datum(sendyouNewData)`

I have used the same code as in the [NVD3 site](http://nvd3.org/ghpages/lineWithFocus.html) the only additional code I added was the chart update function on a button click, oh and the added a width and height to the chart.

The following code is a working tested code. The live code is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/shabeer90/QYVHk/)

Your HTML:

```
<input type="button"  id="change1" value="Change 1"/>
<input type="button"  id="change2" value="Change 2"/>
<div id="chart">
    <svg></svg>
</div>
```

Your JavaScript

```
var dynamic_lineWithFocusChart, lineWithFocusChart;
var width = 500,
    height = 500;

nv.addGraph(function () {
    var chart = nv.models.lineWithFocusChart().width(width).height(height);
    chart.xAxis.tickFormat(d3.format(',f'));
    chart.yAxis.tickFormat(d3.format(',.2f'));
    chart.y2Axis.tickFormat(d3.format(',.2f'));

    dynamic_lineWithFocusChart = d3.select('#chart svg').datum(testData());
    dynamic_lineWithFocusChart.transition().duration(1000).call(chart).attr('width', width).attr('height', height);

    nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);

    lineWithFocusChart = chart;
    return chart;
});

/*
 * Simple test data generator
 */
function testData() {
    return stream_layers(3, 128, .1).map(function (data, i) {
        return {
            key: 'Stream' + i,
            values: data
        };
    });
}

/*
 * Update the Line Focus chart with the Button Click
 */
$("#change1,#change2 ").click(function () {
    dynamic_lineWithFocusChart.datum(testData());
    dynamic_lineWithFocusChart.transition().duration(1000).call(lineWithFocusChart);
    dynamic_lineWithFocusChart.update
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the response! I looked at your example and it's similar to what I want but still slightly different. Ideally, when I click on change1 or change2, it would change the viewfinder to a different range, and have that affect the main graph as well. Think of something similar to an interactive stock chart from Yahoo where you can click on preset time ranges (1D, 5D, etc) and it changes the range of the viewfinder for you.

Comment: @user1924355 - As far as I know your requirement cannot be met with NVD3.js since it was built in an attempt to re-use charts and chart components. You might have to create your own version, NVD3 has given you a starting point. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks again. I decided to use D3 directly to accomplish what I wanted. NVD3 seems like a good library but just not for our purposes.